# hg commit opens an editor

Tags: mercurial

when I run `hg commit`, vim editor is opened and shows

```
HG: Enter commit message.  Lines beginning with 'HG:' are removed.
HG: Leave message empty to abort commit.
HG: --
```

and shows some paths. What does that mean? what is the next step?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enter any information about your commit there. The message you enter will be shown in commit history `hg log`. You should briefly describe the changes made in your commits, because documented history is easier to track.

The next step is to save the temporary file in the editor to finalize the commit: `:wq`.

To avoid spawning an editor, you can enter the commit message directly on the command line using the `-m` option: `hg commit -m "This is a commit message"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
hg commit -m"Your message" -uNAME
```

`NAME` replaced with your username or similar.